# Can't Resume after Suspend

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, suspend, logo

#### Cant Log in after suspend

After i click suspend my PC goes to sleep mode and everything is fine. But when i click the power button i get a black screen with all kinds of awful colored lines all over it. It must be the ***log in screen*** but i can't type my password the keyboard does not work. After a few seconds the monitor shuts down and the only way to fix this is a hard reset. Does anyone have a similar problem ?

I have installed the nVidia drivers by opening a program called Additional Drivers and it is activated cause i see a green light at the bottom.

I have Ubuntu 12.4 LTS 64 Bit. My CPU Type is QuadCore Intel Core i7-2600, 3400 MHz. My Main Memory is 12268 MB. And my Graphic Card is ***NVIDIA GeForce GT 545*** .

**Here is the screen i get when i try to wake up PC from Suspend**:
[image: screen after resuming from suspend]

#### Ubuntu Logo missing on start up

Also when i start my PC and choose Ubuntu from the grub menu i don't see the Ubuntu Logo loading, just a purple screen and after a few seconds i get into Ubuntu. On my other PC i see Ubuntu logo which is loading. Why is that ?

[image: Ubuntu Logo on Start Up]

**Hear are my partitions**
[image: my partitions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem with resuming from suspend. First in the Additional Drivers Program i installed a beta experimental version of nVidia.

**Then i did this in myterminal:**

- sudo apt-get install v86d
- gksu gedit /etc/default/grub

Here i replaced  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
with this one: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1280x1024-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap"`

Also i replaced `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480`
with this one: `GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024`

- gksu gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/modules

I added the following line at the end of the file:  `uvesafb mode_option=1280x1024-24 mtrr=3 scroll=ywrap`

- echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
- sudo update-grub2
- sudo update-initramfs -u
- Reboot Ubuntu

Both problems are now solved. The Boot Splash Screen and the resume from Suspend. But now i get the feeling that the system is booting a little longer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following will help

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```